# TeXstudio: images in tooltips

Tags: graphics, texstudio

TeXstudio (I am using v.2.6.6 on Win 7) shows small image tool tips for PDF files as in

```
   \includegraphics[width=2.7in]{figs/logos.pdf}%
```

when you hover over the filename. This works very well for pdfs. In my tests, png images show in the tool tips, but not scaled in a small box. When I hover over a png the tool tip image can fill my entire screen (depending on the resolution on the png).

Jpeg's do not seem to show at all in the tool tips.

I have not been able to find any documentation on this potentially useful feature. If it worked consistently with jpegs as well as pdf's, it would certainly help in the preparation of Beamer presentations.

Does anyone know how this feature is supposed to work and what the constraints are? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are currently always shown unscaled. PDFs contain a definition of their intended size. Pixel images are shown 1:1 (1 pixel in the image = 1 pixel on the screen).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about jpegs? They don't seem to show at all.

Comment: Currently jpegs only work with the extension .jpg; support for .jpeg will be included in the next release. Also there will be an option to limit the width of image tooltips.

Comment: Thanks for this! Currently I cannot get images files with jpg extension to work--only png. In general, this would be a great feature if it worked consistently with (at least) png, jpg and pdf if, as you say, the width of the image tooltip could be limited. If I am allowed to say this here, many thanks for your dedicated work on this program!